# What is the best way to detect motions on video when the camera moves?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, motion-detection, opticalflow, video-tracking

What is the best way to detect motions of objects on video (exclude ego motion of camera) when the my camera moves?

I have real-time 50 FPS fullHD 1920x1080 video-stream. Camera has ego motion.

I.e. I must do:

- estimate motion of my camera between 1st and 2nd frames (translation, scale and rotation)
- compensate this movement of my camera - reversed move 2-nd frame
- use [`gpu::MOG2_GPU`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/gpu/doc/video.html#gpu::MOG2_GPU) to detect motions of objects - the difference between the two frames

What is the best way (the fastest and the best quality) to compensate movement of the my camera?

1. [`phaseCorrelate()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#Point2d%20phaseCorrelate(InputArray%20src1,%20InputArray%20src2,%20InputArray%20window)) - get only translation and very slow
2. [`cv::videostab`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d50/group__videostab.html#gsc.tab=0) - class designed to eliminate jitter and video stabilization
3. for each frame calculate ([`gpu::SURF_GPU`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html#gpu::SURF_GPU) or [`goodFeaturesToTrack()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#void%20goodFeaturesToTrack(InputArray%20image,%20OutputArray%20corners,%20int%20maxCorners,%20double%20qualityLevel,%20double%20minDistance,%20InputArray%20mask,%20int%20blockSize,%20bool%20useHarrisDetector,%20double%20k))) and [`estimateRigidTransform()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#Mat%20estimateRigidTransform(InputArray%20src,%20InputArray%20dst,%20bool%20fullAffine)) - get affine transformation (translation, scale and rotation) but is very slow for HD real-time video
4. for every 50 th frame (1 times per 1 sec) calculate ([`gpu::SURF_GPU`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html#gpu::SURF_GPU) or [`goodFeaturesToTrack()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#void%20goodFeaturesToTrack(InputArray%20image,%20OutputArray%20corners,%20int%20maxCorners,%20double%20qualityLevel,%20double%20minDistance,%20InputArray%20mask,%20int%20blockSize,%20bool%20useHarrisDetector,%20double%20k))) and [`estimateRigidTransform()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#Mat%20estimateRigidTransform(InputArray%20src,%20InputArray%20dst,%20bool%20fullAffine))
5. use approach 4, but with custom implementation of [`estimateRigidTransform()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#Mat%20estimateRigidTransform(InputArray%20src,%20InputArray%20dst,%20bool%20fullAffine)) - use ([`calcOpticalFlowSF()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowsf) or [`calcOpticalFlowFarneback()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowfarneback) or [`DenseOpticalFlow::calc`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#denseopticalflow-calc)) instead of [`calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowpyrlk): https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3942b1f36261b196a264eb35c996222848fe3c93/modules/video/src/lkpyramid.cpp#L1439

What is the best of these 5 approaches, and if this is 4, then what is the best of OpticalFlow-functions:

- [`calcOpticalFlowSF()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowsf)
- [`calcOpticalFlowFarneback()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowfarneback)
- [`DenseOpticalFlow::calc`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#denseopticalflow-calc)
- [`calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowpyrlk)

Comment: I always wanted to try dense optical flow to combine it with visual flow patterns analyzed by Gibson (psychologist) but didnt find the time/project for it :D

Comment: @Micka This is an important point, that we are about (visual flow patterns) James Gibson, but not about (Pattern Recognition novel) William Gibson :) James Gibson's (1966) bottom up processing, which is vs Gregory's (1970) top down processing: http://www.simplypsychology.org/perception-theories.html  Do you think should try it to compensate ego motion?

Comment: probably it is quite slow, but I like it in theory... but it was really just a comment, no idea whether it will work. Good luck with the question, I like that you presented many candidates of how to solve the problem.

Comment: @Micka  I'll try to use `gpu::PyrLKOpticalFlow::sparse()` or `gpu::PyrLKOpticalFlow::dense()`, then `gpu::meanShiftSegmentation()` to separate different flows by clear boundaries, and then for each segment build two `std::vector<Point2f>` with source coordinates (each 5 pixels) and destination coordinates (calc from source and flow from step_1) of points in this segment, and try to find affine transformation `Mat affine = cv::estimateRigidTransform(src_pts, dst_pts)`, and compare each affine transformation with each Gibson's visual flow patterns.  Or is it possible to make somehow better?

Comment: The biggest segment of flow - must be a ego motion of camera. Others - movement of objects.

Comment: would be similar approach I would try but somehow compare the whole flow with gibson patterns. maybe with ransac so the object movements become outlier

Comment: @Micka I already tested something like this but with sparse flow. I use `Mat affine = estimateRigidTransform(frame1, frame2)`, then compensate ego motion `gpu::warpAffine(frame2, frame2_warped, affine, frame2.size(),  WARP_INVERSE_MAP);`, and then detect motions of objects `gpu::MOG2_GPU` for `frame2_warped`. `estimateRigidTransform()` uses sparse flow https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3942b1f36261b196a264eb35c996222848fe3c93/modules/video/src/lkpyramid.cpp#L1439 and RANSAC https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3942b1f36261b196a264eb35c996222848fe3c93/modules/video/src/lkpyramid.cpp#L1467

Comment: @Micka `affine` transformation (translation, scale and rotation) well describes Gibson's optical flow patterns, and RANSAC well filter out outliers (random noise). But if we have 2 big movements: 1-st background (ego motion), 2-nd hood of the car, or moving my hand close to the camera, or moving big object, then `estimateRigidTransform()` with RANSAC calculates **average transformation between these 2 big movements**- bad compensation of ego motion and bad 
background subtraction. Then I want to have a way to manualy customize threshold of the boundary separation between the massive movements.

Comment: hi there, just curious; what did you end up doing to achieve this?